Setting different colors for specific items in semPlots
I want to set a different color for items Q3 and Q9 (for example) to highlight these items as in the following figure:

Is there any trick to make that happens. I have tried to learn and done trial and error for the past few weeks but no luck.
The following are the data and my codes:
library(lavaan)
library(semPlot)

baseData<- c(1,2,3,4,5) # categories
s <- 500 # sample size
set.seed(11)
catdata <- data.frame(
  Q1 = sample(baseData, size = s, replace = TRUE),
  Q2 = sample(baseData, size = s, replace = TRUE),
  Q3 = sample(baseData, size = s, replace = TRUE),
  Q4 = sample(baseData, size = s, replace = TRUE),
  Q5 = sample(baseData, size = s, replace = TRUE),
  Q6 = sample(baseData, size = s, replace = TRUE),
  Q7 = sample(baseData, size = s, replace = TRUE),
  Q8 = sample(baseData, size = s, replace = TRUE),
  Q9 = sample(baseData, size = s, replace = TRUE),
  Q10 = sample(baseData, size = s, replace = TRUE),
  Q11 = sample(baseData, size = s, replace = TRUE),
  Q12 = sample(baseData, size = s, replace = TRUE),
  Q13 = sample(baseData, size = s, replace = TRUE),
  Q14 = sample(baseData, size = s, replace = TRUE),
  Q15 = sample(baseData, size = s, replace = TRUE)
  )

my_model <- '
Factor 1 =~ Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4 + Q5
Factor 2 =~ Q6 + Q7 + Q8 + Q9 + Q10
Factor 3 =~ Q11 + Q12 + Q13 + Q14 + Q15
'

model_fit <- cfa(my_model, data = catdata)

plot <- semPaths(model_fit, whatLabels="std", layout="circle2", style = "lisrel", 
                        curve = 2, rotation = 3, shapeLat = "ellipse", shapeMan = "circle", sizeMan = 6,
                        nCharNodes = 0, intercepts = FALSE, residuals = FALSE,  exoCov = TRUE, edge.label.cex = 0.75, nDigits = 2, edge.label.color = "black")


Make sure to use get_edges() from the tidySEM package, not ggraph:
edges <- tidySEM::get_edges(model_fit)
edge_color <- ifelse(edges$to %in% c("Q3", "Q9") & edges$arrow == "last",
  "orange", "black")

plot <- semPaths(model_fit, whatLabels="std", layout="circle2", 
  style = "lisrel", curve = 2, rotation = 3, shapeLat = "ellipse", 
  shapeMan = "circle", sizeMan = 6, nCharNodes = 0, intercepts = FALSE,
  residuals = FALSE,  exoCov = TRUE, edge.label.cex = 0.75, nDigits = 2,
  edge.label.color = "black", edge.color = edge_color)


Thanks a lot for your help. This works for my case.

Just my $0.02 in case anyone else is having trouble setting the colours/widths -- the what argument must be set to display an unweighted network (e.g. the default paths value) so that the edge.color and edge.width arguments can work as expected.

edges <- get_edges(model_fit)
edge_names <- unique(c(as.character(edges$from), as.character(edges$to)))

edge_colors <- ifelse(edge_names %in% c("Q3", "Q9"), "orange", "black")

Get the list of edges from the model. If the edge is either Q3 or Q9, it assigns orange; otherwise, it assigns black. Set semPaths argument edge.color = edge_colors

It says Error in get_edge(fit) : could not find function "get_edge" Did I miss anything? What other packages should I load? Thanks

It worked after I load ggraph, but when I run edge_colors <- ifelse(edges %in% c("Q3", "Q9"), "orange", "black") it says Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) :    'match' requires vector arguments

fit is your fitted model object. In your code that is model_fit. So try edges <- get_edges(model_fit)

I have edited my answer.get_edges from ref https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidySEM/vignettes/Plotting_graphs.html
